# Out of Memory Picasso Lib

Tags: android, memory, out

I'm developing an app that loads a lot of images through lib Picasso. When I'm navigating through the app, suddenly the app crashes, giving out of memory.
I already tried to do somethings to avoid this kind of problem, but with no success.

If someone could help me, i would be glad.

Below the code:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.codal.whatsee/com.codal.whatsee.fragmentactivity.ItemPostFragmentActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary 
XML file line #55: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2217)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5141)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #55: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:343)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
at com.codal.whatsee.fragmentactivity.ItemPostFragmentActivity.onCreate(ItemPostFragmentActivity.java:150)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2171)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:594)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:429)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2208)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:129)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:119)
at com.codal.whatsee.utils.SquareImageView.<init>(SquareImageView.java:13)
... 26 more
```

OBS: This problem happens not just in this class, but in any other class happens too.

Comment: The leak that leads to an `OutOfMemoryError` can be anywhere.  The allocation that failed and crashed could be innocent.  Only you can help yourself on this one.  You need to learn to use a heap analyzer like Eclipse MAT and find out where the leak is.

Comment: Apparently, OutOfMemory happens when you try to load a big image in an ImageView from XML, at least this is what the stack trace suggests. If it's so - Picasso has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Egor That's incorrect, and that's why `OutOfMemoryError`s are so tricky to debug.  Picasso could very well be the culprit.  It may use up most of the memory, and then an innocent `ImageView` comes along and crashes the app with a small allocation.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede, Yes, that's actually true, missed that point. Thanks for noticing!

Comment: I've already tried to skip Memory Cache when Picasso loads an image, however the app still crashes. I even tried to debug and analyse the heap, but no success. The object that takes more memory is the byte[]. Is there any way to clean this object?
I'll try to do the heap analyzer again, if someone else knows how to solve this problem, I would appreciate.

Comment: Please, see the next answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916867/picasso-gives-out-of-memory-when-load-an-image

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like your application is leaking memory and the image decoding is just the last operation that fills the heap. You should use the android DDMS tools and create a heap dump of your app after short use. If you see many Activities or Fragments in the dump, you should try to figure out which objects are still holding references to them.

Here is the related page from the developer site:
https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html

Answer (score 0):

You may be getting OOM because of the following:

1. You are doing some operation that continuously demands a lot of memory. Like Picasso Lib fetching large images/bitmaps which plays with bitmap operations

   - Picasso uses fit() or resize() methods while fetching the images. [ReferenceLink](http://blogs.innovationm.com/android-out-of-memory-error-causes-solution-and-best-practices/)
2. Memory leaks:  You didn’t made the previous objects you allocated eligible for Garbage Collection (GC)

   - Use memory analyzer tool for taking Dump check where object are getting leak.
3. Dealing with large bitmaps. Scaling and bitmap operation take the memory from the heap.

I came across this link. It may help you : [Link](http://blogs.innovationm.com/android-out-of-memory-error-causes-solution-and-best-practices/)

Answer (score 0):

You can expect such exception when dealing with images and bitmap. In present case it appears that out of memory is due to loading of a large/big image which consume the available memory and creating issue.

Luckily picasso lib offers an option to scale down your image so that it may not consumed much memory and thus lower down the chances for getting out of memory exception.

See if this below code is helpful to you or not.

```
Picasso.with(context).load(file).resize(sizeToScaleDown, sizeToSacleDown).onlyScaleDown().into(imageView);
```

Note: onlyScaleDown() function only works if you have also used resize() function. Using onlyScaleDown() function without resize() function will cause you exception.

Answer (score 0):

Android 4.2 and 4.3 do not free the memory for a bitmap unless you finish the activity using the bitmap or recycle it (`Bitmap.recycle()`). See [Android Bitmap Memory Analysis - Part 3. API Version Comparison](http://lab.tigerpenguin.com/2014/03/android-bitmap-memory-analysis-part-3.html) for a detailed analysis. In Android 4.3 you need to additionally remove the image view from the view hierarchy.

So if you have an app where you can build up a deep navigation history and are using Picasso, you will run out of memory sooner or later because Picasso does not track references to bitmaps and therefore cannot call `Bitmap.recycle()` for them.

We had a similar issue and finally switched to Facebook's [Fresco library](http://frescolib.org/), which goes at great length to track references. It is therefore more complex too use but it pays off.